# Code does not print colision moment as expected

Tags: python, loops, pygame, bullet, current-time

Just to clarify the context:

I am not sure what error is happening. My code was built to display a window using **pygame** containing an image of a **player** and a **enemy** image, in addition to a **red surface** that automatically slides down the screen. Note: This code contains parts of codes in http://programarcadegames.com/.

Now my question:

But I wanted to add an impression of the time exactly **when the enemy is hit by the bullet** launched by the player.
The question arises from the fact that its use `print (currentTime)` the moment it is printed is different from the moment when the enemy is hit. But if you use `print(time.time () - startTime)` the moment is marked as expected.
To check for this divergence I used a **stopwatch** and starting from the beginning of the **code execution** on my terminal until **approximately 7 seconds** (when I hit and eliminate the **enemy** from the screen) I got two different results that confirm the existence of this question.

**Case 1** (using `print (currentTime)`): start the code execution and simultaneously start the timer somewhere outside (your smartphone for example). Hit the enemy and eliminate him from the screen in approximately 7 seconds and also simultaneously stop the external timer. Result: terminal receives the impression by marking something like `0.5645756721496582`.

**Case 2** (used `print(time.time () - startTime)`): start the code execution and simultaneously start the timer somewhere outside (your smartphone for example). Hit the enemy and eliminate him from the screen in approximately 7 seconds and also simultaneously stop the external timer. Result: terminal receives the impression marking something like `7.940780162811279`.

I want to know what is the cause of divergence when I use `print(time.time () - startTime)` and when I use `print(currentTime)`.

As I am not a python expert, I ended up not using "good practices" on how to write the relationship logic between the player, bullet and the enemy and their respective renderings on the screen. But I believe that this does not interfere with the legitimacy of my question in itself.

**Here my code that works:**

```
import pygame
import random
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key
import time

#store start timestamp
startTime = time.time()

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

#create window

size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size) 


#class 

currentTime = time.time() - startTime



class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the block. """
    def __init__(self, color):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 15])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK) 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Diego(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.image = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert()
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
class Apple(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.image = pygame.image.load("spr11.png").convert()
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
          self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK) 
class Bala(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 10])
          self.image.fill(BLACK)
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
      def update(self):
         self.rect.y += -3

# Setup
pygame.init()
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])

bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group() 

#def block and include and track in the class Block

#for i in range(50):
#    # This represents a block
#    block = Block(BLUE)

#    # Set a random location for the block
#    block.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
#    block.rect.y = random.randrange(350)

#    # Add the block to the list of objects
#    block_list.add(block)
#    all_sprites_list.add(block)

apple = pygame.image.load("spr11.png").convert()
block = Apple()
player_image = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert()
player = Diego()


block.rect.x = 200
block.rect.y = 200

block_list.add(block)
all_sprites_list.add(block)

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Hide the mouse cursor
x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0

rect_x = 50
rect_y = 50
rect_change_x = 1
rect_change_y = 1
x = 0
y = 0
#player.rect.y = rect_x
#player.rect.y = rect_y
score = 0
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    x += x_speed
    y += y_speed

    # --- Event Processing
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
#bullet  
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Fire a bullet if the user clicks the mouse button
            bullet = Bala()
            # Set the bullet so it is where the player is
            bullet.rect.x = x
            bullet.rect.y = y
            # Add the bullet to the lists
            all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
            bullet_list.add(bullet)



            # User pressed down on a key
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_speed = -3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_speed = -3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 3 

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            # If it is an arrow key, reset vector back to zero
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 0


    for bullet in bullet_list:
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
            score += 1
            print(score)
            print("BLUE")
            print(time.time() - startTime)
        if bullet.rect.y < -10:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
    all_sprites_list.update()
    # --- Game Logic


    # --- Drawing Code



    # First, clear the screen to WHITE. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.
    screen.fill(WHITE)

#    x += x_speed
#    y += y_speed
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    player_image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    apple.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    screen.blit(player_image, [x, y])   
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [rect_x, rect_y, 10, 10]) 
    rect_x += rect_change_x
    rect_y += rect_change_y
    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Limit frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

# Close the window and quit.
pygame.quit()
```

**Here my code that doesn't work as expected**

```
import pygame
import random
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key
import time

#store start timestamp
startTime = time.time()

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

#create window

size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size) 


#class 

currentTime = time.time() - startTime



class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the block. """
    def __init__(self, color):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 15])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK) 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Diego(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.image = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert()
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
class Apple(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.image = pygame.image.load("spr11.png").convert()
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
          self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK) 
class Bala(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 10])
          self.image.fill(BLACK)
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
      def update(self):
         self.rect.y += -3

# Setup
pygame.init()
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])

bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group() 

#def block and include and track in the class Block

#for i in range(50):
#    # This represents a block
#    block = Block(BLUE)

#    # Set a random location for the block
#    block.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
#    block.rect.y = random.randrange(350)

#    # Add the block to the list of objects
#    block_list.add(block)
#    all_sprites_list.add(block)

apple = pygame.image.load("spr11.png").convert()
block = Apple()
player_image = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert()
player = Diego()


block.rect.x = 200
block.rect.y = 200

block_list.add(block)
all_sprites_list.add(block)

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Hide the mouse cursor
x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0

rect_x = 50
rect_y = 50
rect_change_x = 1
rect_change_y = 1
x = 0
y = 0
#player.rect.y = rect_x
#player.rect.y = rect_y
score = 0
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    x += x_speed
    y += y_speed

    # --- Event Processing
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
#bullet  
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Fire a bullet if the user clicks the mouse button
            bullet = Bala()
            # Set the bullet so it is where the player is
            bullet.rect.x = x
            bullet.rect.y = y
            # Add the bullet to the lists
            all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
            bullet_list.add(bullet)



            # User pressed down on a key
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_speed = -3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_speed = -3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 3 

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            # If it is an arrow key, reset vector back to zero
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 0


    for bullet in bullet_list:
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
            score += 1
            print(score)
            print("BLUE")
            print(currentTime)
        if bullet.rect.y < -10:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
    all_sprites_list.update()
    # --- Game Logic


    # --- Drawing Code



    # First, clear the screen to WHITE. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.
    screen.fill(WHITE)

#    x += x_speed
#    y += y_speed
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    player_image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    apple.set_colorkey(BLACK)
    screen.blit(player_image, [x, y])   
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [rect_x, rect_y, 10, 10]) 
    rect_x += rect_change_x
    rect_y += rect_change_y
    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Limit frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

# Close the window and quit.
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I can tell you're never updating your currenttime variable.
so simply add

```py
 currentTime = time.time() - startTime
```

inside your mainloop and it should work.